# Update all columns in database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to traverse all table column and replace all columns having value of "." with null values in sql server. So here I wrote some logic. But somehow its not working.

```
create table #AllColumns  
  (  
  ColNo int not null primary key identity(1,1),  
  ColumnName varchar(100)  
  )  
  insert into #AllColumns  
  SELECT  c.name ColumnName  
FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN
     sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id INNER JOIN
     sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
   where t.name='TabelName'


DECLARE @i int  
DECLARE @numrows int  
DECLARE @columnName varchar(100)  
   set @i=1  
   set @numrows= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #AllColumns)  
   IF @numrows > 0  
    WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(ColNo) FROM #AllColumns))  
    BEGIN  
        set @columnName=(select ColumnName from #AllColumns where ColNo=@i)  
        update TabelName   
        set @columnName=null  
        where @columnName='.'  
        set @i=@i+1  
    END  
drop table #AllColumns
```

let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a variable on the left side of an equals in a set or a where like that. In other words, this is legal

```
update MyTable set myColumn = null;
```

but this is not:

```
update MyTable set @myColumn = null;
```

You can accomplish this using dynamic SQL, meaning building SQL as a string and then executing it. Something like:

```
 declare @MyColumn nvarchar(max) = 'Column1';
 declare @sql = 'update MyTable set ' + @MyColumn + ' = null;'

 exec(@sql);
```

Comment: How would you write in Dynamic SQL: update MyTable set [Col1] =NULL where [Col1] ='.'

Comment: Just add it to the string specified as @sql, like `declare @sql = 'update MyTable set ' + @MyColumn + ' = null where ' + @MyColumn + ' = ''.''';` Remember, you're programmatically generating a sql statement and then running it.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
declare @Countt bigint

SELECT @SQL = STUFF(( SELECT ' ; Update ' + INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_NAME + ' SET YourColumnName = YourValue' 

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES LEFT OUTER JOIN  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ON INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_NAME = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME where INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_TYPE =N'BASE TABLE' AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_NAME = N'YourTableName' AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME =N'YourColumnName'
FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')

SET @SQL = @SQL

PRINT @SQL
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```